# React object initial state is overriden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, use-state

I got a react component with a form. I keep the form settings in an object outside the component:

```
const initialForm = {
name: {
    elementType: 'input',
    elementAtts: {
        label: 'Tenant Name', 
        readOnly: false        
    }, 
    isRequired : true,      
    value: '',
},
description: {
    elementType: 'input',
    elementAtts: {
        label: 'Description',
        readOnly: false 
    },    
    isRequired : false,  
    value: '',
}
}

const AddAndDisplay = (props) => 
{ 
   const [formSettings, setFormSettings] = useState(initialForm); 
   ... 
}
```

the `elementAtts` is the attributes I pass the input.

What I'm trying to do is open a modal which displays the form - one time for display only and one time with editing allowed - can be for editing an existing item or for adding a new item.

I'm doing it like this for editing an existing item and for displaying:

```
//a callback
const OpenModalForEditOrDisplay = (isEditable, cardObject) =>
{
      setFormSettings(prevForm => 
        { 
          let newForm = {...prevForm};
          newForm.name.elementAtts.readOnly = !isEditable;
          newForm.description.elementAtts.readOnly = !isEditable;
          return {...newForm} 
        });
       setIsFormOpen(true);
    }
  };
```

and for adding a new item:

```
setFormSettings(initialForm); 
setIsEditing(true); 
setIsFormOpen(true); //this is merely a state saying if to show the modal with the form
```

The user can then submit or cancel the form, and on either case I'm doing:

```
setFormSettings(initialForm);
```

The problem is that it seems like `initialForm` is overridden and if I open the form for display only, it stays on display when trying to open the form for addition because the code for the edit part changed what I thought would be a copy of the `initialForm`. If I remove these lines in the open for edit function the form stays with the initial form's settings:

```
newForm.name.elementAtts.readOnly = !isEditable;
newForm.description.elementAtts.readOnly = !isEditable;
```

Why is the initial form being overridden here?

Comment: maybe,try let newForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevForm)); ?

Comment: Another best practice use an useEffect side-effect to set formSettings, catch initialForm property changes and set formSettings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used Spread syntax to clone the prevForm values within setFormSettings. However you must note that Spread syntax only shallow clones the object and does not perform a deep cloning which means that you nested values within the prevForm still hold the original reference and when you update the values like

```
newForm.name.elementAtts.readOnly = !isEditable;
newForm.description.elementAtts.readOnly = !isEditable;
```

You are mutating it at the original reference. The correct way to update state is to immutably update it by cloning each nested level like

```
setFormSettings(prevForm => 
    { 
      let newForm = {
           ...prevForm, 
           name: {
              ...prevForm.name,
              elementAttrs: {
                 ...prevForm.name.elementAttrs,
                 readOnly: !isEditable,
              }
           }
           description: {
              ...prevForm.description,
              elementAttrs: {
                 ...prevForm.description.elementAttrs,
                 readOnly: !isEditable,
              }
           }
        };
      return newForm;
    });
```

Comment: And also you can use some immutability helper lib. That easies on nested or deep objects. You easily update and use new clone, you don't need to make deeper spreads.

https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem for Deep Copy and shallow copy. The 'formSettings' data source is 'initialForm'. Use 'setFormSettings' will to change 'initialForm' , this is right. Because you use a shallow copy when you initialize it. you can use a function Deep Copy to 'initialForm'.

```
const createInitialForm = () => ({
name: {
    elementType: 'input',
    elementAtts: {
        label: 'Tenant Name', 
        readOnly: false        
    }, 
    isRequired : true,      
    value: '',
},
description: {
    elementType: 'input',
    elementAtts: {
        label: 'Description',
        readOnly: false 
    },    
    isRequired : false,  
    value: '',
}
})

const AddAndDisplay = (props) => 
{ 
   const [formSettings, setFormSettings] = useState(createInitialForm()); 
   ... 
}
```